# Google Maps - Load denied by X-Frame-Options

Tags: google-maps

I have a map I created under Google Maps. I've set the option to "Public on the web - Anyone on the Internet can find and view"

I click on "Embed on site", grab the code and dump it on my page.

It displays ok in Chrome when logged into Google but in Firefox (with Firebug) it shows

`Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://accounts.google.com...`

Similarly in IE. What gives? How to resolve?

In addition, when I try to view the maps outright, it asks me to log into Google first

UPDATE: https://code.google.com/p/maps-engine/issues/detail?id=77

Comment: Works for me without problems(no matter if logged in or not), can you post a link to your site?

Comment: Works for me as well without any sign in (on Firefox/Chrome) since I gave the map public view access. However, here's a question with a lot of hacks and/or solutions for the issue you are facing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options